# Import existing library with JavaScript ES6 Modules

Tags: javascript, import, module, ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-6

How can an existing library be loaded and run using JavaScript's ES6 Modules?

For example, suppose I need to load an existing polyfill:

```
import {poly} from "thirdParty/poly";
```

How can I run the imported `poly` script and load its properties into the current namespace without changing the source?

Here are two practical problems to help clarify the problem I'm trying to solve:

1. I have a script called `rafPolyfill.js` which is a polyfill for window.requestAnimationFrame. I need to import it into the global scope and run it immediately as soon as it loads. This is easy to do with a `<script>` tag:

It runs and loads itself into the global scope. How is can this be done using ES6 modules?

2. I have another script called `Font.js` which is a pre-loader for fonts. It let's you create new font object like this:

   var font = new Font();

I used Font.js by loading it with a script tag, like this:

```
<script src="Font.js"><script>
```

Without accessing, changing, or understanding the source code of this script, how is it possible to use ES6 modules to load and use the in the same way that I would with a `<script>` tag? I just need these scripts to run when they're loaded and take care of themselves.

A possible solution might be using the module Loader API:

http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:module_loaders

This document describes *global binding* of the `System` loader, but I'm afraid I don't have the vocabulary to fully understand what it's trying to explain. Any help in decoding this document would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is: "No, based on the ES6 spec it's not possible to load and run a global script the same way you can with a script tag."

But there is a solution: SystemJS

https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs

It's a universal module loader for ES6 modules, AMD modules, and global scripts (anything you load with the `<script>` tag)

Answer (score 3):

Does this or something close to this work for you?

```
var stuffFromPoly = import "thirdParty/poly"
```

Then you would call methods off of the object stored in `stuffFromPoly`.

If that's not quite it, could you expand your question a bit, I'm trying to guess at exactly what you mean and I may be a bit off.

**Quick note post-'your update':**

Are you opposed to using https://www.npmjs.org/package/es6-module-loader ?  Or does that not quite solve the problem?

From the readme:

> The new ES6 module specification defines a module system in JavaScript using import and export syntax. For dynamically loading modules, a dynamic module loader factory is also included in the specification (new Loader).
>
> A separate browser specification defines a dynamic ES6 module loader loader for the browser, window.System, as well as a  tag for using modules.
>
> This polyfill implements the Loader and Module globals, exactly as specified in the 2013-12-02 ES6 Module Specification Draft and the System browser loader exactly as suggested in the sample implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: Are you opposed to using https://www.npmjs.org/package/es6-module-loader ? Or does that not quite solve the problem?

Comment: @Enalyr: As long as it uses syntax that matches current version of the Module spec and I can get it working with Traceur and/or es6-module-loader, I'm happy :)